# CodeIgniter matching var val to mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

If I have a value in a variable, how do I test to see if that value is already registered in a MySQL db using Ci framework?

Comment: we're going to need more information. to begin with, the table structure would be good.

Comment: What do you mean by already registered in a MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to check if a value exists in table, then you could do:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('your_table_name', array('field_name' => $yourVariable), $limit, $offset);
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Ref: [Database Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)
Hope it helps